# Pop Os taking long time to boot and start certain programs

Tags: performance, pop-os, troubleshooting

I apologize that this question has been asked before. I looked at the answers on those questions but am still struggling. I have recently switched to Linux after using Windows for decades.

I've been trying to diagnose what is causing my computer to take so long to start up and even after it's running, why it takes certain programs *minutes* to open. I installed **Stacer** and according to it, my CPU rarely gets above 30%. Memory and Disk hold steady at 5.0/31.2GiB and 481.5GiB/1.8TiB respectively.
I've run the following commands:

```
$ systemd-analyze

Startup finished in 14.269s (firmware) + 724ms (loader) + 9.426s (kernel) + 9min 2.073s (userspace) = 9min 26.494s 
graphical.target reached after 9min 1.850s in userspace
```

(I am not going to paste the whole report, just the first few lines)

```
$ systemd-analyze blame

8min 15.130s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1min 32.685s snapd.service
1min 8.444s udisks2.service
48.472s networkd-dispatcher.service
37.869s user@112.service
34.705s dev-sda3.device
33.440s dev-loop8.device
33.395s dev-loop6.device
33.345s dev-loop7.device
33.309s dev-loop9.device
33.231s dev-loop10.device
33.188s dev-loop5.device
32.767s dev-loop0.device
32.755s dev-loop3.device
32.579s cups.service
32.575s dev-loop2.device
32.080s systemd-journal-flush.service
31.726s dev-loop4.device
31.123s dev-loop1.device
```

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

graphical.target @9min 1.850s
└─multi-user.target @9min 1.850s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @46.718s +8min 15.130s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @46.392s +303ms
      └─network.target @46.363s
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @41.060s +5.302s
          └─basic.target @40.393s
            └─dbus-broker.service @40.125s +262ms
              └─dbus.socket @40.080s
                └─sysinit.target @40.075s
                  └─snapd.apparmor.service @39.365s +710ms
                    └─apparmor.service @37.752s +1.601s
                      └─local-fs.target @37.751s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-hplip\x2dprinter\x2dapp.mnt.mount @2min 6.891s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 49.208s
                            └─swap.target @39.270s
                              └─dev-zram0.swap @43.668s
                                └─dev-zram0.device @41.508s
```

I have no idea how to find out what's causing some programs to take so long to start unfortunately.

I've seen some sites talk about disabling the `plymouth-quit-wait.service` to speed things up but I'm still not completely sure that *plymouth* is the problem. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

> Welcome, could you give some details on the hardware? Is it PC or laptop, the disk is SSD or HDD? Have you tried other distros? This is happening right after installing or started later? Maybe after a kernel update? – schrodingerscatcuriosity

It's a PC I built back in 2016. It has:

- 2TB SSD
- i7-6700k CPU
- NVIDIA GEForce GTX 1070 GPU

I haven't really tried other distros because it's my understanding that the base would be the same and it's just the additions that change. It doesn't start immediately. It'll run fine for a while and then start having these issues. If I've this wrong, I'd definitely be willing to try other distros.

Comment: Welcome, could you give some details on the hardware? Is it PC or laptop, the disk is SSD or HDD? Have you tried other distros? This is happening right after installing or started later? Maybe after a kernel update?

Comment: I've added some details to the original post

Comment: Some suggestions to review, based on Kubuntu which should be similar. Note it is a 2017 build with new NVMe drive, but I think when I posted the systemd-analyze it still had a m.2 SSD. I updated to larger drive & NVMe was not a lot more cost. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster the NVMe drive is not noticeably faster in my system as SSD was fast compared to previous HDD based system.

Comment: *"that the base would be the same and it's just the additions that change"*. It's more complicated than that. For example different distros can have different kernel version. One thing you can try if you already didn't, is booting with a different version of kernel. I don't know how is in Pop OS, but maybe you have the options in GRUB's advanced options.

Comment: I didn't know that different distros could have different kernal versions. When I was first looking into switching to Linux, I went on to Reddit to get more information. I was informed that the kernals were the same and it was just the desktop environments that were different. I'll definitely try a different distro then. Pop OS' "pop shop" has a nasty of crashing and it's driving me nuts. It's also been a huge pain to get GOG and Epic Games to function right. Maybe a different distro will help with that.

Comment: @MasterOblivious Well, I have in one machine openSUSE tumbleweed and the kernel is 6.4, and in another machine Ubuntu 22 with 6.2, and that 6.2 was updated from a previous version by the OS. (You have here another thing to add in this scenario: rolling vs standard releases in Linux distros landscape). Not only that, each distro may or may not modify the kernel to suit their particular vision.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity I was looking into standard vs rolling releases. It sounds like they both have their pros and cons. One of the distros that I was looking at was an OpenSuse one and another was an Arch one. I'll try another distro and see if that solves my issue. If not, I'll try looking for the solution again

Comment: @MasterOblivious Nvidia + Linux can become problematic (there's a Linus Torvalds' famous reaction about that)... you can try also the OS without the GEForce and see if that could be the source of problems.

Comment: @shrodingerscatcuriosity lol I've noticed that. I'm admitting defeat with Linux and my current build. I designed this rig with Windows in mind so I'll just go back to Windows for the time being. I'll do some research and try and do my next build with more Linux friendly hardware and try again